# Accessing a variable set in cursor outside the cursor in IndexedDb

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want to print the value of variable "set" that I have set inside the cursor, outside my cursor objct.

```
      request.onsuccess = function(e){
      var set = 0;
      var transaction = db.transaction(['List'], "readonly");
      var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('List');

      objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if(cursor) {
        // console.log(cursor.value.Name);
        if (cursor.value.Name == $('#card').val())
        {
          console.log("aisa kabhi hoga hi nahi");
          set = 1;
        }

          cursor.continue();
        } 
        else 
        {
          console.log('Entries all displayed.');
          if (set == 0)
          {
             set= ippp();
             console.log(set);

          }
        }
      };
      console.log(set);
      }
```

When I print my set variable inside the cursor as shown "right data is printed".

But when I try to print the data of variable "set" outside cursor the value that I declared initially gets printed. "How is it possible as I am resetting the value of variable in my cursor"

My question is how can I access the value that I have set to variable "set" inside the cursor, outside of cursor object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about asynchronous programming before using indexedDB. The real answer is to go and learn this.

However, as a quick answer, you can use a callback function.

```
function outerFunction(myCallbackFunction) {
  // do stuff
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.value;

    var value = cursor.value;

    // Here is the whole trick to getting the value out. Pass the value to the 
    // callback function.
    myCallbackFunction(value);
  };
}

// Then to call it, you do something like this, where 'oncompleted' 
// is the name of the callback function

outerFunction(function oncompleted(value) {
  console.log('The value is', value);
});
```

Comment: is it possible to get the cursor returned and `cursor.continue()` to return the next object in the next statement or in an async function? eg. in a manner similar to forEach? (no callback)

Comment: yes that is pretty much what the cursor is, it is an object containing the callback function as a property

Comment: instead of having a callback, can the continue() of the cursor return like in `newObj = cursor.continue();`? and then that can be put into a for loop? or is it necessary that the continue calls a function with the event accepted as a parameter?